# realloc missunderstanding

Tags: c, pointers, realloc

Can somebody explain to me, why this block of code does not work. I was looking through some of questions around but failed finding the answer. Probably because of (huge) lack of knowledge.

Thank you for any given help.

```
char** sentence = malloc(min);
char* temp = malloc(min2);
int i = 0;

while(i<5)
{
    sentence = realloc(sentence, i+2);
    scanf("%s", temp);
    sentence[i] = malloc(strlen(temp));
    strcpy(sentence[i], temp);
    printf("%s\n", sentence[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to account for the fact that strings have null terminators.

Answer (score 1):

```
sentence[i] = malloc(strlen(temp));
```

Should be:

```
sentence[i] = malloc(strlen(temp)+1);
```

You need enough space both for the length of the string (`strlen`) **AND** also for its null-terminator.

Comment: Also: `sentence = realloc(sentence, i+2);` should be `sentence = realloc(sentence, (i+2) * sizeof * sentence );` (and the result from realloc() should be tested before assignment)

Answer (score 0):

```
sentence = realloc(sentence, (i+1) * sizeof(*sentence));
```

would make more sense: you're trying to store `i+1` `char*`s, not `i+2` *bytes*.

BTW, you can just replace the malloc/strlen/strcpy with:

```
sentence[i] = strdup(temp);
```

(that takes care of the nul terminator for you).

Answer (score 0):

```
sentence = realloc(sentence, i+2);
```

is a common anti-pattern. If realloc returns NULL, you've just leaked sentence. Instead you need to write

```
temp = realloc(sentence, i+2);
if(temp == NULL)
  // out of memory - do something here
sentence = temp;
```

To make life worse, you're using

- using scanf which is a common cause of security errors
- using strcpy which is a common cause of security errors
- not checking the result of *any* of your mallocs to see if it returns NULL (if it doesn't you'll get a write-access violation)
- Not adding +1 to the strlen() before calling malloc, and hence getting a 1-byte heap-overflow from the strcpy.
- And using a while loop where a for loop would clearly be more appropriate.

Apart from those six security bugs, you're doing well though.

Comment: Thanks all of you for your help.
Though:
3rd and 5th point is just because I simplified the problem and not posting full code here. Thanks for scanf and strcpy stuff, though if you could send me a link to more info on that would be nice